# what is the use of tivoli directory Integrator?

Tags: tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

I want to know for what purpose is tivoli directory Integrator is used in ITIM environment ?
and how does it function ?

Answer (score 5):

Tivoli Directory Integrator enables synchronization, transformation, and migration of generic and identity data across heterogeneous systems. Tivoli Directory Integrator helps organizations maintain consistent and trusted data across multiple resources and provides:

1. Plug-ins for several popular identity stores such as IBM Tivoli Directory Server, Domino (Http Password only), Microsoft™ Active Directory, and SunOne. These plug-ins securely capture passwords and make them available for processing for AssemblyLines.
2. An infrastructure and several ready-to-use components for solutions that synchronize user passwords in heterogeneous software environments.

**For More Details Check** [this](http://tech.ivkin.net/wiki/IBM_Tivoli_Identity_Manager_Notes) **and** [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-password/)

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple, its a way to transfer data from different systems. You have a lot of control over how to take in the data, modify it, and then output it. For instance, you can take in a csv file from a folder on a server, and then transfer that into a database via a web service.